# Improving turning radius on an under-seat steering recumbent?

Tags: adjustment, recumbent, steering

This under-seat steering tadpole has a pretty large turning radius. The limitation seems to be that the handlebars will bump into the seat. When this happens the actual steering linkage seems like it would have more travel that could be used.

I'm looking for advice on how potentially to improve this. I'm not adverse to some new parts or modifications if that seems necessary / beneficial, but obviously if there is some kind of adjustment that would be worth trying first.

I can start taking things apart but thought it was worth looking for insight here before just monkeying around. In particular I don't want to mess up the wheel alignment or something like that.

Here are photos of the steering linkage etc.:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Its a Sun EZ-Tad CX. Not the lightest thing out there but fun to ride :)

Comment: The steering might become too twitchy!

Comment: @Carel actually it already is a little bit...

Comment: Those photos are not sufficient. In general it should be possible, but not necessarily desirable. The wheels might start hitting your hands.

Comment: Can you lay the trike on its side and take a photo directly from below?  This should show the steering linkages more clearly.   I suspect your ultimate limiting factor will be how far the wheels can turn before hitting something.

Comment: There's a SX variant, specs at http://www.sunseeker.bike/index.php/products/ez-tad-sx/ specifically say **Updates to the EZ-Tadpole SX include Direct Steering**  so there are no pushrods to adjust - that will limit your options a lot sadly.   If yours is more like https://www.sunseeker.bike/index.php/products/t3-cx/ is the  the T3-CX then its also a Direct Steering model.  The underside photo will help a lot.

Comment: @Criggie I've added some more photos, hope they are helpful!

Comment: It looks a lot like an SX (same frame, maybe) but the steering linkage doesn't seem to be the same.

Comment: https://www.utahtrikes.com/PROD-11617645.html claims a turning radius of 62 inches (or 158 cm )  and a Turning Circle of 126 Inches or 320 cm.   Does that match about what yours does at full lock?

Comment: http://www.bentrideronline.com/messageboard/showthread.php?t=35266 says "Stock Sun EZ TADs have a lousy turning radius. Changing to direct steering allowed it to make a very tight u-turn but also made it twitchy. As you can see from the photos I found a better way to put the hand grips in a comfortable place with a reasonable turning radius."  But the photos are gone.

Answer (score 3):

For a start, I would suggest you loosen the indicated pinch bolts, and push the bars forward a little, and rotate them outboard a little.

[image: Mod of OP's photo]

This is an adjustment, not altering the curve in the metal... the sketch is misleading.

- By moving the bars forward in the indicated pinch bolts, you'll get more wheel-turn for the same movement of the handlebars.
- Rotating the bars so they're further apart will give you more space before the bars stop on your seat.

And the best part - all that is completely reversible if you don't like it.

---

Modifying the push rods is going to be a lot more brutal and permanent.  I'd start with a mock up using something cheap and disposable, perhaps plastic pipe or cardboard roll-centers temporarily.

[image: Another annotated version of OP's photo.]

I'm hedging a bit here but I **THINK** moving the pushrod at one or both ends will alter your steering like you want.

Downside is the width of the straight-ahead window will be much smaller, so you're going to have to actively steer a lot more when not turning.

Since its going to be very hard to change the steering arm on the wheel's hub, you might be better off checking with the supplier in case they offer any options to achieve your goal.  A steering arm replacement with a hole that is closer to the kingpin would be much safer than you attempting to drill a new hole for the swivel.  Note that the swivel will be a **tapered hole** too.

The safest solution would be to make an adapter plate that attaches to the main bar, and make two new shorter pushrods.  That way you can revert to stock with no changes.

Also, consider making a scale model of the steering, using cardboard and pins to get an understanding of the relationships between your ideas and their effects.

Comment: I appreciate the thought that went into this. I will definitely start with some adjustments before modifications. Moving the pushrod attachment points seems like it would require shorter pushrods?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs yes you would need to shorten the pushrods, which makes it harder to revert.  So if you can't get the amount of adjust you need by screwing in the ball joints further, then I'd recommend getting some shorter pushrods made in preference to cutting the ends off your existing pushrods.     Also, I think smaller changes would be good here - the pictures are exaggerated to show the differences.   Doing a mock up on the kitchen table would help you explore changes, without messing up the bike.